# Check Null Static Map Variable in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, null

Is there a way in C++ to check if a static map variable is null (meaning, not yet has any mapped key/vals into it)? Consider the following code that does not work:

```
static std::map<std::string,std::string> getOptions(){
  static std::map<std::string,std::string> asOptions;
  if (asOptions != NULL) {
    return asOptions;
  }
  // otherwise, append map items here
  return asOptions;
}
```

See, the process of building the map from a settings file is slower than if the entire asOptions was kept in memory (due to the static keyword on the variable). Thus, I would only check to see if it wasn't already previously assigned and, if it was, simply move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> meaning, not yet has any mapped key/vals into it

To check whether a map is empty or not you should use [`std::map::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/empty).

Anyway, it's not the usual usage of static variable inside function for C++. You can

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> initOptions(){
  std::map<std::string,std::string> asOptions;
  // append map items here
  return asOptions;
}

const std::map<std::string,std::string>& getOptions() {
  // the map will be initialized only at the first time called
  static std::map<std::string,std::string> asOptions = initOptions();
  return asOptions;
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/HZBAW46536)

Comment: Interesting pattern here that I'm not familiar with. So you're saying that once I retrieve getOptions(), I can retrieve it multiple times and it will never go back to a file to read options because it already has them from the initOptions() routine, right? (Assuming that //append... code pulls from file.)

Comment: @Volomike Yes. You can call `getOptions()` multiple times but `initOptions()` will be called only once (the first time).

Comment: The reason I've selected this answer is because it uses less CPU than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35450937/105539) because it doesn't need to calculate size each time. Instead, it uses a C++ feature that reduces calls after the first call.

Answer (score 1):

You must check the size, not that it is not null. The best way to check size is to use .empty() instead of .size() when checking for an empty size. It doesn't necessarily run faster on that condition check, but is more intuitive.

```
static std::map<std::string,std::string> getOptions(){
  static std::map<std::string,std::string> asOptions;
  if (!asOptions.empty()) {
    return asOptions;
  }
  // otherwise, append map items here
  return asOptions;
}
```

Comment: The only thing you check for `NULL` in C++ are pointers. Objects are never `NULL`.

Comment: It's better to use if (!asOptions.empty()) instead of if (asOptions.size() >= 1)

Comment: Can you name a platform where .empty() and .size() produce different machine code in an optimized build? Otherwise their performance will be identical.  The advantage of .empty is that it is clearer (allegedly); in hindsight I think ".empty" was a mistake.

Comment: No, I made an assumption. So, I'll reword this answer.